# Delphi FireDAC TFDQuery DisplayFormat

Tags: delphi, firedac, displayformat

I have some problems related to `FormatOptions`.
I have a sales screen and after migrating to `Firedac`(Previous was `IBO`), full values (ex .: 100.00, 52.00) began to appear like this:

(IBO)
100.00
52.00

(FireDAC)
100
52

I tried to make use of `MapRules` using the following configuration:

```
SourceDataType dtBCD
TagetDataType dtBCD
PrecMax 18
PrecMin 1
ScaleMax 5
ScaleMin 0
```

I actived the `OwnMapRules` option, but the display remains the same. So I tried to make use of `fmtDisplayNumeric property`. Informing a ',0.00' fix my problem in parts, why limit the display to two decimals places, but there are fields that have more than 2 decimal places. Also, my Integer fields are showing decimal places on the display.

I tried to create a rule in MapRules for Integer fields, but the problem remains.

What should I do in such cases?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you using to display this? `TFDQuery` is a non-visual component.

Comment: @JerryDodge i'm displaying in a `DBGrid` and a `DBEdit`

Comment: Typically display should be implemented on the UI level. Meaning, if you're displaying data in a `TDBGrid` and `TDBEdit`, then the display formatting *should* be done there. The underlying data shouldn't be affected.

Comment: I can't format my fields in DBGrid or DBEdit, i always applied the formats using `TNumericField(Query.FieldByName('Field')).DisplayFormat := ',0.00'` on `Query AfterOpen event`. But i know that `Firedac` have this another system called `MapRules`.

Comment: @JerryDodge:  Not sure I agree about where the display formatting should be done, esp. if the same data is to be displayed by two different controls.  What's wrong with using the TField OnGetText event?  Surely this type of thing is what it's intended for.

Comment: @MartynA Well it depends on the purpose. But as a general rule, visual display should be implemented on the presentation level. Perhaps one may need it formatted one way in a grid and another way in an edit. Not saying this is the case here, but very possible.

Comment: @JerryDodge:  Thanks.  I wasn't arguing, just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapRules had nothing to-do with display formatting. It translates a driver data type into the data type you want to use in the application and vice versa.

The IBO components have a specific behaviour for numeric fields. They treat it as a currency field, depending on the numeric scale. See [IBO documentation](http://www.ibobjects.com/docs/TI_Numerics.rtf).

By default, Firedac uses the Regional Settings to format the output. You can read how to change this behaviour in [this paper](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Using_Default_Formatting_for_Numeric,_Date,_and_Time_Fields).